# PC crashed while formating USB Stick from FAT32 to EXT4, now the USB stick won't work

Tags: usb, disk-formatting

I just bought a new 3.0 128gb USB Stick. The USB worked fine and everything. I could put data on it and delete it. Then I wanted to put Ubuntu on this stick to make a bootable USB stick. I followed the instructions of [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g1tZ7X0U-8c&t=530s) and came to the installation point.

During the installation and the formatting of the USB stick my PC just crashed. After I restarted the PC the USB was not recognized by my  PC (using windows). When I put the stick in my PC Explorer shows constantly every second that I need to put a disk in until I disconnect the USB stick.

I tried it to put the stick in my laptop with Ubuntu. If I go to Disks it recognizes the USB.

[image: Picture of the USB]

But Contents is unknown.

I tried the following things:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb
```

but I got an Input/output error.

I tried to format Volume with the GUI but got an error

[image: udisk-error-quark, 0]

The next thing I tried was to download GParted. But got the following error while starting it:

> Input/Output error during read on /dev/sdb,

[image: error message while starting Gparted]

Then I tried to use `ddrescue`:

```
sudo ddrescue --force /dev/zero /dev/sdb
```

I let this program work for an hour but it got nothing.

[image: Picture of ddrescue]

This picture is just an example. My thing was exactly the same just the theme was different.

The last thing I tried was:

```
sudo dosfsck -t -a /dev/sdb
sudo dosfsck -w -r -l -a -v -t /dev/sdb
sudo fsck.vfat -r /dev/sdb
```

All the commands returned an Input/output error

[image: fsck error image]

Did I actually manage to accidentally destroy a completely new USB stick within minutes?

There is no data on this USB stick so it can completely wiped.

Thanks for everyone who is reading this and for everyone who can help me to make this stick workable again.

Best regards :)

---

@theYnot

Output of `dmesg`:

[image: dmesg]

Output of `lsusb`:

[image: picture of lsusb]

Output of `lsblk`:

[image: picture of lsblk]

Comment: I've had success in the past with using `scrub` on the drives to completely wipe them out and in a way it tests them as well at the same time.  `scrub` is in the repos and needs to be installed.  But, I would think that after low level formatting of the drive and still getting an input/output error like that something toasted the drive.

Comment: @Terrance i tried it. Got an Input/Output error :(. But thanks for the idea

Comment: Can you please post (Ubuntu) output from the following commands `sudo lsusb`, `lsblk`. Then remove and reinsert the usb stick and within a few seconds run `dmesg | tail -40`. The first commands should give you information related to your USB drive and the second command should show whether your computer is recognizing it at all.

Comment: output is in the awnsers @theYnot

Comment: IMHO The USB drive looks toasted. Given that it was a new USB, it could probably be a factory defect in it. Try to get it replaced on warranty.

Comment: Please try to format the USB stick with mkusb and then use mkusb to convert it back to normal storage, information is here >> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb

Comment: Going by the data in the images I suspect total failure. Could try `fsck` and `fdisk`. Would be interested to see the output of the commands even if you don't have any luck.